# When using the exiftool `-v` command, Rotation property is misisng

Tags: python-3.x, windows, ffmpeg, metadata, exiftool

I am still not certain if this is the right place to ask, I am currently attempting to backup 60gb+ size videos on my phone to pc, but while doing so I am also trying to leverage FFMPEG and/or exiftool to convert the files to HVEC format (for reduced file size) and to ensure all relevant metadata is copied over from the source file to the converted file.

My question to be specific is related to exiftool in particular where I noticed a discrepancy and was wondering if someone can assist me:

I am currently converting the video files using the following ffmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -i "VID_20220629_201116.mp4" -crf 27 -movflags use_metadata_tags -c copy -c:v hevc_qsv -global_quality 25 -vf scale_qsv=1920:1080 -c:a copy -preset slow "VID_20220629_201116_h265 (2).mp4"`

This does convert the file to H265 but the final file only copies over some datestamps and misses to add/update additional related tags (such as gps) that my phone has added to the source file. But more annoyingly its not detecting the orientation of the source video (which is in portrait) and producing an output in landscape.

I have then written the following python script where I use the the [PyExifTool](https://pypi.org/project/PyExifTool/) module to try and update the file with any missing tags from the original file.

```
import exiftool
from pprint import pprint
import json
from datetime import datetime

video = exiftool.ExifTool()

# Get the path to the file
source_file_path = r"\VID_20220629_201116.mp4"
destination_file_path  = r"\VID_20220629_201116_h265 (2).mp4"

print(f"Source File Path: {source_file_path}")
print(f"Destination File Path: {destination_file_path}\n")

with exiftool.ExifToolHelper() as et:
    source_file_metadata: list = et.get_tags(source_file_path, "All")[0]   
    destination_file_metadata: list = et.get_tags(destination_file_path, "All")[0]
    
    keys_to_check = [];
    source_file_tag_names = source_file_metadata.keys()
    destination_file_tag_names = destination_file_metadata.keys()
    tags_to_update = {}
    
    with open("source.json", "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(source_file_metadata, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        # pprint(source_file_metadata, f)
    
    with open("destination.json", "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(destination_file_metadata, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
        # pprint(destination_file_metadata, f)
    
    for tag in source_file_tag_names:
        if tag not in destination_file_tag_names or "date" in tag.lower():
            keys_to_check.append(tag)
            
            if tag in destination_file_metadata: 
                if destination_file_metadata[tag] == source_file_metadata[tag]:
                    continue
                
            tags_to_update[tag] = source_file_metadata[tag]

    pprint(f"Tags to Update: {tags_to_update}")
    
    if tags_to_update:
        print(et.set_tags(destination_file_path, tags_to_update))
```

This script compares the destination file, with the source file and updates the destination file with any tags that belong in the source file, but not in the destintation file.

In regards to the orientation issue I have, I noticed that if I manually run the following command in the command line:

`exiftool "source_file_name.mp4"`

Then in the output it generates, it displays the property Rotation as follows:

`Rotation                        : 90`

However, this does'nt seem to be captured from my script and therefore I can not see it in the destination file after I run my script. I also suspect this property will help fix my orientation issue that I am currently facing with ffmpeg.

So after looking deeper into exiftool I found that I can add `-v` to the comamand to display output as variable names:
`exiftool -v "source_file_name.mp4"`

After running the above command, from the output I see no variable called or associated to attribute Rotation, and this is why I believe my script is unable to apply to the destination file either.

Sorry I understand my description is long, and I appreciate you taking the time to review it, please let me know if there is a way I can map this Rotation value, and/or if you think there is a much better solution for me to map all the metatags from the source file to the converted destination file.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't address issues with the py script or exiftool but note that your ffmpeg command autorotates the video and so a rotation tag is not needed in the output file.

Comment: `Rotation` is not an embedded tag, it is an [exiftool Composite tag](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Composite.html) which is created by exiftool on the fly.  It derived from the `QuickTime:HandlerType` and the `QuickTime:MatrixStructure`.  If exiftool is not displaying a `Rotation` value, then the most likely problem is that one of those is missing, probably the `QuickTime:MatrixStructure`.  Exiftool only has the ability to edit an existing `QuickTime:MatrixStructure` and cannot create a new one.